# How to prevent ReSharper from creating folders in solution?

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

ReSharper 6 creates folders like `ReSharper.projectname` with the files and folders below in it. That caused a lot of problems with MSDeploy and source control in general. I had to add ignore rules everywhere. What's the right way to prevent that from happening? Is switching back to Visual Studio Intellisense enough?

```
08/05/2011  02:21 PM                 8 AspFileDataCache.dat
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          BuildScriptCache
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          JavaScriptCache
08/05/2011  02:24 PM    <DIR>          JbPdbInfo
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          MVC
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          NamedArguments
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          Resources
08/05/2011  02:25 PM               172 SymbolCache.bin
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          TagPrefixes
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          TodoCache
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          WebSymbols
08/05/2011  02:25 PM    <DIR>          WordIndex
08/05/2011  01:19 PM    <DIR>          XmlIndex
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resharper -> Options, go to the General tab and change "store caches in" to "system TEMP folder" instead of "solution folder"

Answer (score 0):

Resharper 9 just added a new option "Custom folder", so you can put the cache anywhere event in ramdisk